# Periodically execute function in thread in real time, every N seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, real-time

I have a threaded class whose loop needs to execute 4 times every second.  I know that I can do something like

```
do_stuff()
time.sleep(0.25)
```

but the problem is that is doesn't account for the time it takes to `do_stuff()`.  Effectively this needs to be a real-time thread.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  Ideally the thread would still be put to sleep when not executing code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### The simple solution

```
import threading

def work (): 
  threading.Timer(0.25, work).start ()
  print "stackoverflow"

work ()
```

---

The above will make sure that `work` is run with an interval of four times per second, the theory behind this is that it will *"queue"* a call to itself that will be run *0.25* seconds into the future, without hanging around waiting for that to happen.

Because of this it can do it's work (almost) entirely uninterrupted, and we are extremely close to executing the function exactly 4 times per second.

---

More about `threading.Timer` can be read by following the below link to the python documentation:

- **[docs.python.org - 16.2.7. Timer Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects)**

---

#### RECOMMENDED] The more advanced/dynamic solution

Even though the previous function works as expected you could create a helper function to aid in dealing with future timed events.

Something as the below will be sufficient for this example, hopefully the code will speak for itself - it is not as advanced as it might appear.

See this as an inspiration when you might implement your own wrapper to fit your exact needs.

```
import threading

def do_every (interval, worker_func, iterations = 0):
  if iterations != 1:
    threading.Timer (
      interval,
      do_every, [interval, worker_func, 0 if iterations == 0 else iterations-1]
    ).start ()

  worker_func ()

def print_hw ():
  print "hello world"

def print_so ():
  print "stackoverflow"


# call print_so every second, 5 times total
do_every (1, print_so, 5)

# call print_hw two times per second, forever
do_every (0.5, print_hw)
```

---

Comment: Seems nice, but how to stop this?

Comment: This solution is good, however I found that if the work you need to do takes longer than the time period, you'll have a bad time. To stop that I'd recommend waiting until the previous work has finished using a ``Lock`` object.

Comment: How would the above wrapper code work if say print_so has arguments to it, print_so(string1, string2)? I tried this on a function with multiple arguments and get a NoneType object is not callable error

Comment: Hey great solution, this for what ever seems to execute the given function twice each time. I am using this in a flask application. Idk if that has anything to do with it though.

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit different approach with one Thread, looping in a while loop.
For me the advantages are:

- Only one Thread, the other solutions mentioned here starting and stopping threads for every interval
- More control for the Interval, you are able to stop the IntervalTimer with `.stop()` method

Code:

```
from threading import Thread, Event

# StoppableThread is from user Dolphin, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849484/how-to-exit-a-multithreaded-program
class StoppableThread(Thread):  

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_event = Event()        

    def stop(self):
        if self.isAlive() == True:
            # set event to signal thread to terminate
            self.stop_event.set()
            # block calling thread until thread really has terminated
            self.join()

class IntervalTimer(StoppableThread):

    def __init__(self, interval, worker_func):
        super().__init__()
        self._interval = interval
        self._worker_func = worker_func

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            self._worker_func()
            sleep(self._interval)
```

Usage:

```
def hw():
    print("Hello World")

interval = IntervalTimer(1,hw)
interval.start()

sleep(10)

interval.stop()
```