# wxPython: Stuck in .MainLoop()

Tags: python, wxpython

I am not an experienced programmer. This is probably a simple problem to solve.

I have a function that is supposed to run every two minutes. This function is inside a simple wxPython system tray program. The problem is that I do not know how to run the function because wxPython never leave .MainLoop(). Where should I put the function?

Here is the code: (I have left out the function and import because it is not relevant.)

```
TRAY_TOOLTIP = 'System Tray Demo'
TRAY_ICON = 'star.png'

def create_menu_item(menu, label, func):
    item = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, label)
    menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, func, id=item.GetId())
    menu.AppendItem(item)
    return item

class TaskBarIcon(wx.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
        self.set_icon(TRAY_ICON)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)
    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Say Hello', self.on_hello)
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
        return menu
    def set_icon(self, path):
        icon = wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap(path))
        self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)
    def on_left_down(self, event):
        print 'Tray icon was left-clicked.'
        MailCheck()
    def on_hello(self, event):
        print 'Hello, world!'
    def on_exit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)


def main():    
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    TaskBarIcon()
    app.MainLoop()

    #This is my function I want to run
    #But MainLoop() never ends. Where should I put MainCheck() ?
    MailCheck()       

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used wxPython but you could use the threading-module of Python's standard library.

A minimal example:

```
import threading

def work(): 
    threading.Timer(0.25, work).start()
    print "stackoverflow"

work()
```

Look at this thread (example is from there): [Periodically execute function in thread in real time, every N seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488877/execute-function-in-thread-every-n-seconds)

Comment: It did indeed work using the threading-module. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

wxPython, as with most GUI frameworks, uses an event-driven programming model.  That means that bits of your program are run in response to actions that may have originated from the user, (such as a key press, a menu selection, etc.) the system or perhaps from some other program.  The rest of the time it sits in MainLoop waiting for one of those things to happen.

For situations like yours, there is the wx.Timer class which can trigger an event once or perhaps periodically after N milliseconds.  If you bind an event handler for the timer event, then that handler will be called when the timer expires.