# Periodically execute function / SIGSTOP

Tags: python, signals, emulation

I would like to run a project (project.py) that has two scheduling elements like this answer I found on stack overflow: [Periodically execute function in thread in real time, every N seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488877/periodically-execute-function-in-thread-in-real-time-every-n-seconds)

One function is to run every `x` seconds the other every `y` seconds
 where `0.03 < x < 0.1` and  `2 < y < 10`.

`function_x(t)` calls an outside program (sync.py) that pauses (`SIGSTOP`) project.py

Question 0: After calling do_every, the program continues it's execution. Is this a correct assumption?

Question 1: If sync.py takes 2 seconds to execute before calling `SIGCONT` on project.py, will  `function_x`'s Timer be 'messed up'?

Question 3: If `function_y` is sending data over a socket, will  `function_x` calling `SIGSTOP` mess up this execution? Will the timing be paused? How does the timer count time?

Answer referenced earlier:

```
import threading;

def do_every (interval, worker_func, iterations = 0):
  if iterations != 1:
    threading.Timer (
      interval,
      do_every, [interval, worker_func, 0 if iterations == 0 else iterations-1]
    ).start ();

  worker_func ();

def print_hw ():
  print "hello world";

def print_so ():
  print "stackoverflow"


# call print_so every second, 5 times total
do_every (1, print_so, 5);

# call print_hw two times per second, forever
do_every (0.5, print_hw);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0)
After calling do_every - it runs the `worker_func` once and then continues. yes. So your output will be:

```
stackoverflow
After first do_every
hello world
After second do_every
hello world
stackoverflow
....
```

1)
I didn't really know if the timer would be messed up - so I ran a test using `htop` where I can send SIGCONT and SIGSTOP to any process - so, I ran `do_every (2, print_so, 10);` and after 5-6 "stackoverflow"s I stopped it. After a minute on starting it - it spewed out 4 more stackoverflows. So, no - the timer is not messed up.

3)
It will not be messed up - what will happen is that if the socket has a timeout - and you pause for more than the timeout, the other side of the socket will assume your code is dead and will give a timeout exception. But if it's for less than the timeout, the socket will assume it was a temporary disconnection, and will continue streaming the data after that.

Comment: wow thank you for all the answers. I will have to make sure the timeouts are long enough!