# Make os.system('cls') quicker

Tags: python-3.x, os.system

Consider the following code:

```
import time
import os
for a in range(10, 0, -1): # total time is actually 1 second. no float allowed for arg 3.
    print(a)
    time.sleep(0.X) #unknown time...
    os.system('cls')
```

At start of program, `a` is reduced by 1/10 of a second at a time.

Problem:
The `os.system('cls')` takes more than 0.1 seconds to process.
Any solution to make it faster?

Comment: Why do you have a variable as an int both outside your for loop and inside it (as a counter) (the loop variable will override the outside `a` variable)? The above for loop won't run as well because your `(10, 0, 1)` means "start at 10, stop at 0, and step each by 1". I think you meant -1?

Comment: How long is the `time.sleep` going to sleep for (in seconds)? Why is that unknown?

Comment: @user12055579 Time.sleep(x) is unknown because I do not know how long os.system(cls) takes to process. I only know that it's more than one ms because the milliseconds where not milliseconds

Comment: You aren't going to make clearing the screen (or printing) instantaneous, so if you want this loop to run every tenth of a second then you should use a proper clock rather than trying to make your own clock with `time.sleep`. [This other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43892334/12299000) has some examples.

Comment: @kaya3 Is it ok if you can reformulate this into an answer? It would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you're problem is that the for loop runs for more than 1 second because `os.system('cls')` is not instantaneous:

You can test this by using the `timeit` module in Python:

Without `os.system('cls')`:

```py
import time
import timeit
import os
start = timeit.default_timer()
for a in range(10, 0, -1): # total time is actually 1 second. no float allowed for arg 3.
    print(a)
    time.sleep(0.1) #unknown time...
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Output:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
Time:  1.0021432
```

With `os.system('cls')`:

```
Time:  1.7151739000000001
```

You cannot solve this because even without `os.system('cls')` it takes more than 1 second. The function `os.system('cls')` itself already takes about `0.1649219` seconds to execute. You cannot make Python library function faster.

Comment: @ user 12055579 This is helpful, its that I am running this in cmd and I would like to clear screen to display a different output each time. Thanks anyway!

Comment: OK, this is a bit late, but I actually found my own solution: make the cmd window smaller. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can make the cmd window smaller to take less processing time. It works!
Having less pixels to generate and clear makes it an ideal option.

```
def count():
    for a in range(10, 0, -1):
        print(a)
        time.sleep(0.1) #I know I am breaking the DO NOT USE TIME.SLEEP rule.
        os.system('cls')
count()
```

As said above, it's never reliable to use time.sleep, but if you shrink the window, it comes close. (I think it doesn't have to be spot on.)