# Exiting a multiprocessed python application safely

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I noticed that `os._exit(<num>)` ::

> Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers,
>   flushing stdio buffers, etc.

and that `sys.exit()` ::

> “only” raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called
>   from the main thread

I need a solution to close a multi-processed application that will ensure all processes are closed (none left orphaned) and that it exits in the best state possible.

Extras:

I am creating the processes using the python multiprocessing library, by creating classes which inherit from `multiprocessing.Process`

Comment: see this question 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849484/how-to-exit-a-multithreaded-program

Comment: Thanks @jbaldwin this is dealing with threading which is different to multiprocessing. Threads will be killed with the main thread being terminated where-as with multiprocessing you can end up with child processes persisting.

Comment: How do you create the processes? If you create them with `subprocess`, then you can call [`Popen.terminate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) to kill all the children processes and then exit using `sys.exit`. If you are in a child process you can send a message to the main thread to do this for you.

Comment: @Bakuriu I create the process by extending the python multiprocessing.process classes

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a Pipe for every Process.  Then when the main Process shuts down it can send a message to all the children Processes that they should shut down too.

In order to make that work right you've got to put a periodic check into the children Processes' "do loop" to see if there are messages in the pipe, and if so, check them to see if it's a "quit now" message.