# terminate Python multithreaded program with log output

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Issues**

I currently have a simple **Python** multithreaded server program, which will run forever with out manual interruption. I want to achieve that it can be terminated gracefully at some point. Once it is terminated, I want the server to output some stats.

**Solutions I have tried**

1. Terminate the program by `kill`. The issue is that the server cannot output the stats because the HARD termination.
2. Create a control thread in the program, which listens the key input. And if key is pressed, then terminate the program and get stats. The issue with this approach is I need to do every step manually. E.g, SSH to the device, start the program, and press key at some point.

**Question**

Is there a way that I can run some **bash/or other program** to stop the program gracefully with stats output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit a multithreaded program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849484/how-to-exit-a-multithreaded-program)

Comment: I don't think so. My point is I know how to stop all running threads in my Python program. I want the server be terminated by some external signals. Otherwise, I will let the server keep running.

Comment: In that case, you can catch an external signal from within and then gracefully exit from the thread. Either way, for a graceful exit, you have to implement the exiting functionality in the thread itself, by reading some flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use [signal.signal()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal) to register a handler for e.g. `SIGTERM`? There you could implement this part of code that throws out the statistics and then just terminate the program.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to either

- make threads sufficiently short-lived
- at the stop signal, stop spawning new ones and `.join()` the active ones.

or

- make threads periodically (e.g. after serving each request) check some shared stop flag and quit when it's set
- at the stop signal, set the stop flag, then `.join()` the threads

Some threads can be `.setDaemon(True)`, [but only if they can be safely killed off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation) (there's no exception or anything raised in the thread, it's just stopped where it is).

[If a thread is in a blocking call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359597/gracefully-terminating-python-threads), it may be possible to unblock it by shutting down the facility that it is waiting on (close the socket or the stream).